# Palindrome Swift CCC J3

Tags: swift, function, sorting, search

I'm trying to figure out how to find a Palindrome in a specific word given. ie - banana the Palindrome would be anana. I have a function that allows me to check if the whole word is one but I don't know how to check in the word if any part of it is a Palindrome. Any ideas on what could fix this?

```
var word = "anaana"


 func isPali(word:String) -> Bool {

    let characters = Array(word)
    var currentIndex = 0

    while currentIndex < characters.count / 2 {
        if characters[currentIndex] != characters[characters.count - currentIndex - 1] {
            return false
        }
        currentIndex += 1
    }

    return true
}

if isPali(word: word) {
print(word.count)
}else{
print("Not a Pailidrome")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below `functions`.

```
func isPalindrome(_ word: String) -> Bool {
    return word == String(word.reversed())
}


func findPalindrome(in word: String) -> String? {
    var subString: String = word
    for i in 0...word.count {
        guard isPalindrome(subString) == false else { return subString }
        subString = word
        subString.remove(at: word.index(word.startIndex, offsetBy: i))
    }
    return nil
}
```

The `isPalindrome` will simply check if a word is palindrome. The `findPalindrome` function will check for all the `subStrings` in the given `word` if there is any palindrome and if it exist, that `string` will be returned.

Comment: The code works really well except if I try to put abracadabra in, for example, it shows the whole word, not the palindrome aca in the middle of the word.

Comment: Actually while posting the answer i had doubts for these kind of scenarios but tried to give you the simpler solution that you can work upon. For this scenario, you might have to break the word into sub strings where each sub string will have 3 characters in it and then check if it is palindrome.